# EC2: There was a problem connecting to your instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, instance

"There was a problem connecting to your instance
We were unable to connect to your instance. Make sure that your instance’s network settings are configured correctly for EC2 Instance Connect. "

my instance is running and the status shows all ok, but I can see my website:

https://hadara.space

I'm new in this world so, I don't know what is the problem because the last week it was working correctly but today no more.
i can connect via ssh but when i try to connect via AWS show me the first message, thanks for any idea

[image: imagen 1]

[image: imagen 2]

Comment: When I follow that link, I cannot see your website. When I do `nslookup hadara.space`, it is returning two results: `34.192.68.249` AND `54.211.255.106`. That seems strange. Also, please show us the configuration of your Security Group inbound rules.

Comment: @JohnRotenstein sure

Comment: its enough?  or do you need another setting?

Comment: Are you saying that you can connect to the instance via SSH, but it does not work if you try to connect using **EC2 Instance Connect**, or are you asking a different question?

Comment: i can not connect EC2 Instance Connect, the console return me a error

Comment: You will need to modify the Security Group rules to permit inbound connections from _Anywhere_ (bad for security), or from the range of IP addresses used by the _EC2 Instance Connect_ service. See the duplicate question for details.

Comment: That's because you have configured a rule to allow ssh only from your IP in the security group's inbound rule. When you use AWS EC2 Connect, the request is not coming from your IP address. Allow from '0.0.0.0/0' and retry connecting using EC2 Connect.

Comment: @Zakir yeah I was able to solve the problem. thank you so much